# Bash read with delimiter past newlines

Tags: shell-script, csv, newlines, read

I have a csv for which I have to extract a specific field. The csv is pipe-delimited (`|`), with double quotes (`"`) to protect text fields and (this is the catch) newlines in some of the text.

eg.

```
"aaa"|"111"|"!!!"|""
"bbb"|"222"|"@@
@"|""
"ccc"|"333"|"###"|""
```

I would like to extract the second field of each record:

```
111
222
333
```

I am using a bash script to read the file, but it seems the `read` command stops when it reaches a newline, even when `-d` is specified. That means, in the above example, that my script processes record 1 correctly (I use `read -d \| varname`), but not record 2, because it doesn't recognise the newline as part of the third field. Now it sees `@"|""` as a new record and everything gets messy.

Is it at all possible to use `read` for this, or should I look at alternatives?

I've spent **DAYS** playing around with `read`'s settings and searching on the web. Funny thing, I came across someone with a problem on the exact same kind of input file that I have, but that problem was with Excel.

Comment: Is your 2nd column the only one contain digits?

Comment: No, any field can contain any type of data, and any field can contain newlines.

Answer (score 4):

For a shell with a `read` builtin that can handle CSV, you can use `ksh93` instead of `bash`:

```
$ while IFS='|' read -rS a b c; do printf '%s\n' "$b"; done < file
111
222
333
```

To convert that format to something that `bash`'s `read` can handle, you could do:

```
< file ksh93 -c 'while IFS="|" read -rSA a; do
                   printf "%s|" "${a[@]//[\|]/\\\0}"
                   printf "\0"
                 done' |
       bash -c 'while IFS="|" read -d "" a b c; do
                  printf "%s\n" "$b"
                done'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using a proper CSV parser. For example, using the one that ships with ruby:

```
ruby -rcsv -e 'CSV.foreach("file", :col_sep => "|") {|row| p row; puts row[1]}'
```

we get

```
["aaa", "111", "!!!", ""]
111
["bbb", "222", "@@\n@", ""]
222
["ccc", "333", "###", ""]
333
```

You can see for the 2nd row, there is the embedded newline. Remove `p row` to get rid of those "debugging" lines.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the best solution for me (but I guess it's a matter of taste), was using PHP's `fgetcsv`, since I already have PHP on that server. It's a pity the bash `read` command doesn't handle the newlines as well as the PHP function. It automatically recognises additional delimiters (like "'s).

Sample:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, "|")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "$num fields in line $row:\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $c + 1 . ": " . $data[$c] . "\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Output (for example in my original question):

```
4 fields in line 1:
1: aaa
2: 111
3: !!!
4: 
4 fields in line 2:
1: bbb
2: 222
3: @@
@
4: 
4 fields in line 3:
1: ccc
2: 333
3: ###
4:
```